# How to show/hide DIV by clicking radio button?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

By default the both DIV's should be hidden. By selecting the radio button, have to show the appropriate DIV (following its #ID).

Below is my code:

```
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' id="bank"/>
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' id="school"/>

<div id="bank" class="none">Bank</div>
<div id="school" class="none">School</div>

<style> .none { display:none; } </style>
```

But we have to show only one div at a time. Is it possible?

Comment: call hide() function of jquery for onchange event

Comment: Don't use 2 same id's on single page.

Comment: like @KamilT said, your HTML is invalid here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `data-*` attribute here like:

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="bank" />
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="school" />
```

JS

```
$(':radio').change(function (event) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#' + id).addClass('none').siblings().removeClass('none');
});
```

[**WORKING FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SgXSR/)

Answer (score 11):

This can be done using CSS.

Note: The `<div>`s must be general siblings of the `<input>` element.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="showGreen"> Green
    <input type="radio" name="showRed"> Red
    <div id="green">I am the green div.</div>
    <div id="red">I am the red div.</div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#green, #red {
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
}

#green {
    background-color: #6f6;
}

#red {
    background-color: #f44;
}

input[name="showGreen"]:checked ~ #green,
input[name="showRed"]:checked ~ #red {
    display: block;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ly56w/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' id="bank"/>
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' id="school"/>

<div id="bank_div" class="none choice">Bank</div>
<div id="school_div" class="none choice">School</div>
```

JS:

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function(event) {
    var myId = this.id;
    var targetId = myId + "_div";
    $("div.choice:not(#" + targetId + ")").addClass(".none");
    $("#" + targetId).removeClass(".none");
});
```

Comment: This does not show the corresponding div on click, but hides it

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution using jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
function showBank()
{
$("#bankDIV").removeClass("none");
$("#bankDIV").addClass("showDIV");

//Make sure schoolDIV is not visible
$("#schoolDIV").removeClass("showDIV");
$("#schoolDIV").addClass("none");
}

function showSchool()
{
$("#schoolDIV").removeClass("none");
$("#schoolDIV").addClass("showDIV");

//Make sure bankDIV is not visible
$("#bankDIV").removeClass("showDIV");
$("#bankDIV").addClass("none");
}
</script>


</head>
<body>

<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' id="bank" onclick="showBank()"/>
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' id="school" onclick="showSchool()"/>

<div id="bankDIV" class="none">Bank</div>
<div id="schoolDIV" class="none">School</div>

<style> 
.none { display:none; }, 
.showDIV { display:block; } 
</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Make sure that no doubled IDs are presented in your code. And that only one DIV is visible at a time.

Regards, 
Alex

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' id="bank"/>
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' id="school"/>

<div id="bankDiv" class="none">Bank</div>
<div id="schoolDiv" class="none">School</div>

<style> .none { display:none; } </style>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
        var rad = $(this);
        ('input[type="radio"]').addClass('none');
        if (rad.is(':checked'))
            ('#' + rad.attr('id') + 'Div').removeClass('none');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Please select Your Payment Option:</label><br>
        <input id='watch-me1' name='payment' type='radio' class='show-me1' value="Cash On Delivery" checked /> Cash On Delivery<br />
        <div id='show-me1' style='display:none;border:1px solid black;color:red;'>Not Available At This Moment!</div>

        <input id='watch-me2' name='payment' type='radio' class='show-me2' value="Bkash/Rocket Mobile" /> Bank<br />
        <div id='show-me2' style='display:none;border:1px solid black;'>Not Available At This Moment!</div>

        <input id='watch-me3' name='payment' type='radio' class='show-me3' value="Credit/Debit Card" /> Credit/Debit Card<br />
        <div id='show-me3' style='display:none;border:1px solid black;'>Not Available At This Moment!</div>

        <input id='watch-me4' name='payment' type='radio' class='show-me4' value="Paypal" /> Paypal<br />
        <div id='show-me4' style='display:none;border:1px solid black;'>Not Available At This Moment!</div>
    <script>
          $(function(){
          $(':radio').click(function() {
          $('#' + $(this).attr('class')).fadeIn().siblings('div').hide();
          })
         .filter(':checked').click();
          });
     </script>

    </div>
```

Comment: Some additional explanations about this code-only answer would probably be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you it is not a better approach that you use same id for 2 or more controls...

Please make a unique id for each element.

use this code...

```
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' id="bank"/>
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' id="school"/>

<div id="radio_divs">
<div id="bank_div" class="none">Bank</div>
<div id="school_div" class="none">School</div>
</div>
<style> .none { display:none; } 
.view { display:block; }
</style>
```

now use onclick on radio button...

```
jQuery("input[type=radio]").click(function(event) {
    jQuery('#radio_divs').children('div').each(function () {
        jQuery(this).addClass(".none");
    });
    jQuery("#" + this.id + "_div").addClass(".view");
});
```

It will definitely works and make it visible only a single div and rest divs make it invisible....

Answer (score 0):

you can try this as well,

```
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' id="bank"/> <input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' id="school"/>

<div id="bankDiv" class="none">Bank</div> <div id="schoolDiv" class="none">School</div>
```

css

```
.none { display:none; }
```

jquery

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
        var rad = $(this).attr('id');           
            $('#' + rad + 'Div').show();
            $('#' + rad + 'Div').siblings('div').hide();
    });
});
```

check out this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/f2UKj/